# AvalonEdit CompletionWindow is not showing when break point is enabled

Tags: debugging, avalonedit

I am using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit for Text Editor. When I am in debug mode with enabled breakpoints, CompletionWindow is not showing in the TextEditor. When disable the breakpoints then CompletionWindow is showing. Anyone facing this issue ? Because of this, I could not debug the code with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CompletionWindow closes itself when the TextEditor loses focus.

If you really need to debug focus-sensitive code in a debugger, try using a secondary machine and remote debugger. (the second machine can just be a virtual machine)